# Regex - string repetition of min length

Tags: javascript, regex, replication, string-length

I want to find any string repetition. I have following code:

```
let match: Object;
let repetition: ?string;
while ((match = /(.+?)\1+/g.exec(string)) !== null && repetition === null) {
  repetition = match[1];
}
```

It finds 'abc' replication in 'weabcabcjy', but it also finds 'll' in 'all'. I would like to have regex to limit minimal length of replication to 2 characters. It means it compare always minimally 2 characters against others two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+?` pattern finds any *one* or more  chars other than linebreak characters, so `ll` in `all` will get matched since the first `l` will be captured into Group 1 and the second one will be matched with `\1+`.

To only find repetitions of 2+ character chunks you may use a lazy *limiting* quantifier `{2,}?`:

```
/(.{2,}?)\1+/g
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYu3O9/1).

The `(.{2,}?)\1+` pattern will match and capture into Group 1 any two or more, but as few as possible, characters other than linebreak symbols and then 1 or more same consecutive substrings.

Comment: I was trying (.?){2,}\1+ but this way hasn't occurred to me. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, that [`(.?){2,}\1+`](https://regex101.com/r/dIjvQ3/1) looks spooky. Quantifying an optional pattern leads to matching an empty string. Avoid capturing repeated groups in JS, unless you are trying to remove consecutive repeatitions with a single occurrence.